# Как реализовать переход назад по fragment-ам в navigation drawer

Tags: android

У меня есть navigation drawer . В `listView` я выбираю `item`  заменяю `fragment1`, в `fragment1` из списка выбираю `item`  и заменяю `fragment1` на `fragment2`...

Как вернуться назад по фраментам? По нажатию левой верх кнопки открывается navigation drawer. Это все происходит в одном activity. Правильно ли я это делаю? Можно пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот только что (минуту назад) решал аналогичную задачу.

**Что нам надо:**

1) При запуске активити показывать гамбургер.

2) При замене фрагмента поменять гамбургер на стрелку.

3) При нажатии на стрелку вернуть предыдущий фрагмент

4) Опять показать гамбургер.

---

**Делаем:**

1) Если ND сделан правильно, то гамбургер уже показан при запуске.

2) Показать стрелку можно так:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

3, 4) Она будет реагировать на нажатия в onOptionsItemSelected() по id R.id.home

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //При нажатии вызывается обработчик кнопки назад
            //Он по умолчанию должен будет вернуться по списку фрагментов назад
            onBackPressed();
            //Надо вернуть иконку гамбургера
             mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme) решали подобную задачу на англо-саксонском.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, все отлично работает. Заодно узнал для себя пару полезных методов!

Comment: Пожалуйста дайте рабочий код. У меня ND, из домашнего frame заменяю фреймом "типа подробнее об карточке"-стрелка назад есть,но не нажимается.

Comment: Показывает стрелку ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); - вызываю из фрейма. Но принажатии на стрелку вылазит меню.

Comment: @pl_roman, пункты 3 и 4 у вас сделаны?